# How to apply $arrayToObject to the array output by $push in mongodb aggreggation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The code below (with the two lines commented out)

```
    myComments.aggregate(
        { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
        { $match: query },
        { $group: {
            _id: {
                activity: "$activity",
                writer: "$writer"
            },
            summary: {
                // $arrayToObject: {
                    $push: {
                        "k": "$userID",
                        "v": "$commentText",
                    }
                // }
            },
        } },
        { $project: { _id: 0 } },
        ( err, data ) => {
            console.log( JSON.stringify( data || [] ) );
        }
    )
```

produces "summary" arrays as expected:

```
    [ {"summary":[ {"k":183044,"v":"adf"}, {"k":184817,"v":"be"}, {"k":187252,"v":"c"} ]},
      {"summary":[ {"k":183044,"v":"146"}, {"k":184817,"v":"25"}, {"k":187252,"v":"3"} ]} ]
```

However, when I remove the comments and allow `$arrayToObject` to act upon those arrays the output `data` is undefined.

Am I using one or both of these commands incorrectly? Is it incorrect to nest them this way?

Comment: `$push` builds an array so you should move `$arrayToObject` to the next pipeline stage. `{ $addFields: { summary: { $arrayToObject: "$summary" } } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$group` when each documents is being iterated respective below object will be pushed into `summary` field, So at the end of group stage `summary` would be an array of objects.

```
{
    "k": "$userID",
    "v": "$commentText"
}
```

Additionally you can not apply `$arrayToObject` to summary cause your keys (**k**'s) are not strings. So if $userID is not a string you need to convert it to string in group stage. Try as below :

```
   myComments.aggregate(
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
    { $match: query },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                activity: "$activity",
                writer: "$writer"
            },
            summary: {
                $push: {
                    "k": { $toString: "$userID" },
                    "v": "$commentText",
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            summary: {
                $arrayToObject: "$summary"
            }
        }
    },
    (err, data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data || []));
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about requiring strings for the "k" value. I'm not sure I would have ever figured that one out!

Comment: @KeithVoss : Yes just think of **JSON** where keys in an object will usually be string, So as query response would be a kind of converted to **JSON** or at-least **BSON** in DB, So all object's keys should be probably be strings..